# How 'cloud of choices' is called correctly?

Tags: website-design, gui-design, design-patterns, design, javascript

I'm working on a react-native app and I want to implement a similar interface, but I can't even find its name.

Main task for this element would be to give users a "cloud of choices" where they could select multiple of "bubbles" and system can keep a track of choices. "Bubbles" should be able to float around and bounce from each other.

How this design element is called?

Also, are there any ready to use packages that implement it?

[image]

Comment: What you're asking is not clear, so I suggest trying to ask more clearer. Which design are you trying to ask from the given photo? Try to describe the way it moves even if you don't know it's name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the word you're looking for is "Tag Cloud".

Additionally, the size of the cloud (circles, in your example) usually depends on pre-defined parameters.

For example, you can visit Stackexchange's website: https://stackexchange.com/sites and notice that the size of the box depends on the number of people in the community (and other parameters as well, which are unknown to me).

Answer (score 0):

This is commonly refferred to as [**bubble chart**](https://www.google.com/search?q=bubble+chart&tbm=isch&ved=2ahUKEwjj_LifrtTmAhUC_hoKHQjLBMUQ2-cCegQIABAA&oq=bubble+chart&gs_l=img.3..0l10.5644.7986..8072...1.0..0.71.843.13......0....1..gws-wiz-img.......0i67.RrLVHFLiEXc&ei=8jMFXuO7O4L8a4iWk6gM&bih=789&biw=1440).

Probably the most common package for charts (for [web-design](/questions/tagged/web-design)) is [chart.js](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/bubble.html)

```
var myBubbleChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bubble',
    data: data,
    options: options
});
```

As for floating and bouncing, I doubt that. Then it's no longer a chart. But it shouldn't be too hard, you probably might wanna use [canvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API) and [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) data into each bubble.